# Use leaflet map object outside useEffect in react

Tags: reactjs, react-leaflet

I have a button that will edit the mymap object (for example add marker or circle).
But it give me error that says "mymap is not defined".
I have tried declare the mymap var outside the useEffect but it doesn't work because useEffect doesn't save the assignment. I also tried useState but it doesn't work either.

here's my code

```
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'
import L from 'leaflet/dist/leaflet'
import { useEffect, useState} from 'react'

import './css/grid.css'

export const Grid = ({mapID}) => {
    const centerCoor = //redacted
    var layerGroup = L.layerGroup()

    function addGrid(){
        var btnel = document.getElementById("btn-grid");
        btnel.classList.toggle("btn-active");

        if (btnel.classList.contains("btn-active")){
            // do something with "mymap"
            mymap.on('click', (e)=>{
            })
        }
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        var mymap = L.map(mapID, {
            center: centerCoor,
            zoom:18
        });

        L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}', {
            attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
            maxZoom: 18,
            id: 'mapbox/satellite-v9',
            tileSize: 512,
            zoomOffset: -1,
            accessToken: //redacted
            }
        ).addTo(mymap);


        

        return () => {
            mymap.off()
            mymap.remove()
        }
    },[])


    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={addGrid} className="" id="btn-grid">ADD GRID</button>
            <div id={mapID}>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are creating the map using `L.map()` instead of using a `<MapContainer>` element from `react-leaflet`. If you want to use `leaflet` inside of `react`, you should use this library: https://react-leaflet.js.org

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaflet keeps track of its state separately from React, which is why it's best to use the [React-Leaflet binding](https://react-leaflet.js.org/). If you are going to use vanilla Leaflet inside of React, you should consider setting up a `useEffect` hook that handles creating the map instance and setting the map instance to state. Then you can access the map instance to add event listeners, add markers/popups, etc. This also helps React keep track of Leaflet's current state and monitor for any changes. Here is an example component:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import L from 'leaflet';

const MapComponent = (props) => {
  // Map state:
  const [mapInstance, setMapInstance] = useState(null);
  const [marker, setMarker] = useState(null);

  // Map refs:
  const mapRef = useRef(null);
  const tileRef = useRef(null);
  const markerRef = useRef(null);

  // Base tile for the map:
  tileRef.current = L.tileLayer(
    `https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`,
    {
      attribution:
        '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
    }
  );

  const mapStyles = {
    overflow: 'hidden',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100vh',
  };

  // Options for our map instance:
  const mapParams = {
    center: [37.0902, -95.7129], // USA
    zoom: 3,
    zoomControl: false,
    zoomSnap: 0.75,
    layers: [tileRef.current], // Start with just the base layer
  };

  // Map creation:
  useEffect(() => {
    mapRef.current = L.map('map', mapParams);
    // Add an event listener:
    mapRef.current.on('click', () => {
      alert('map clicked');
    });
    // Set map instance to state:
    setMapInstance(mapRef.current);
  }, []); // <- Empty dependency array, so it only runs once on the first render.

  // If you want to use the mapInstance in a useEffect hook,
  // you first have to make sure the map exists. Then, you can add your logic.
  useEffect(() => {
    // Check for the map instance before adding something (ie: another event listener).
    // If no map, return:
    if (!mapInstance) return;
    if (mapInstance) {
      mapInstance.on('zoomstart', () => {
        console.log('Zooming!!!');
      });
    }
  }, [mapInstance]);

  // Toggle marker on button click:
  const handleClick = () => {
    if (marker) {
      marker.removeFrom(mapInstance);
      markerRef.current = null;
    } else {
      markerRef.current = L.marker([40.7128, -74.006]).addTo(mapInstance);
    }
    setMarker(markerRef.current);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>
        {`Click to ${marker ? 'remove' : 'add'} marker`}
      </button>
      <div id="map" style={mapStyles} />
    </>
  );
};

export default MapComponent;
```

Here is a live sandbox I've set up so you can test it out:
[LIVE DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-5mat1e?file=src/MapComponent.jsx)

Comment: So the first useEffect is to set the mapInstance and the other is only if we need to use it if something change in mapInstance. Just tried implement this to my code and it works, I can access the mapInstance outside the useEffect. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, you've got it. It's best to keep the creation logic separate from any logic that updates or makes changes to the instance. No problem, happy to be of service!